# Text reader that allows me to seek to different lines

Tags: java, file-io

I am looking for a text reader that supports line-based seeking. I would like it to support encodings as well. For example, it might have a method that looks like

```
 seekLines(n, seekType) - goes to a particular line based on the seek type
```

The seek type would be similar to how it's done for binary files: from the beginning of the file, from the current position, maybe from the end.

For example, suppose I have the following lines:

```
1   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
2   sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
3   Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
```

And I am currently at line 2. If I say

```
seek(1, CURRENT); // arbitrary constant
```

Then it will go to line 3. If I say

```
seek(1, BEGIN);
```

It will go to line 1.

Is there a library available that provides this?

Comment: A 4K user should know this is off-topic...

Comment: A question about libraries is on-topic as defined in the help center.

Comment: But "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."? The beginning of your post looks like a set of requirements for the library you ask for at the end.

Comment: Yes, I would like to know if anyone has used a library that provides that functionality.

Comment: I guess I could frame the question as "this is how I've done it, but I don't like how these things are implemented, how can ____ be done instead" and then hope someone suggests a library they're using to avoid re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You need an index of the text lines to go to random lines. The simplest solution is to read all the lines into `List<String>` and look this up randomly.

---

If you can't fit all the text in memory, you can index all the lines.  This can be done lazily to a memory mapped file so it doesn't have to use significant heap.  You would need to read all the lines up to the point you are looking for, but you only have to do this once.

Comment: No, lets keep this interesting and say that the file is bigger than the heap.   Sucking it all in crashes the program :)

Comment: Thanks, currently I've got my own class that uses a BufferedInputReader internally to read it into an arraylist and using the indexing as suggested. The line indexing is an interesting approach that I didn't think of (since all uses cases so far have been reasonable file sizes)